# How to obtain image/png content via PHP

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

This is my first post to Stack Overflow so please forgive me if I have used incorrect formatting or conventions.  I am trying to write a test scenario which receives a png image from a webpage POST (multipart/form-data), strips out the image which was posted and forwards that on to a 3rd party as Content-Type: image/png.

I have a php file (catcher.php) which is the recipient of the forwarded image.  Post.php, the php file that posts the uploaded image to catcher.php is below:

```
<?php
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
    imagepng($img);
    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"POST",
            'content'=>$img,
            'header'=>"Content-Type: image/png\r\n"               
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    file_get_contents( "http://localhost/catcher.php", false, $context);
?>
```

Post.php gets the file just fine from the webpage that posts it as multipart/form-data, however I am unsure how to access the image/png content in catcher.php.

My question is, in catcher.php, how do I access the image content?  I have tried $_POST['content'] and I obtain the following error: "Undefined index: content".  So I know I am just not looking for the correct data.  Is there a specific superglobal variable such as $_POST or $_REQUEST that I can use to access the posted image content, or is there some other solution?

**RESOLUTION**
I was able to find the result I was looking for with the following code for catcher.php:

```
$input = fopen("php://input","+r");
$destination = fopen($target_path, 'w');

stream_copy_to_stream($input, $destination);

fclose($input);
fclose($destination);
?>
```

Thank you both Marc and Brenden for your expedient responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imagepng($img)` does an immediate output of the binary garbage comprising the PNG. it's not captured into a variable. What you're actually posting is a string that probably says "GD Resource #7" or something similar.

The whole imagepng() bit is useless anyways - you're decoding a PNG into an in-memory representation, then trying to re-encode to PNG again. A pointless waste of memory, since the file is already on disk. You could do the whole thing with:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES['myfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['myfile']['error']);
}

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"POST",
        'content'=> file_get_contents($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']),
        'header'=>"Content-Type: image/png\r\n"               
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_get_contents( "http://localhost/catcher.php", false, $context);
```

Note the addition of checking for upload success - assumingn an upload succeeded will cause you grief down the line.

That being said, you're also not doing a proper POST file upload. For that to work, you have to actually simulate a full-blown HTML form with `<input type="file">` present, and `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and whatnot. All you're doing is sending a raw PNG to the server.

You can probably retrieve it by reading from `php://input` in your catcher script.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I did have some code up above the code that I posted that checked to ensure that the upload was successful, however the part about the imagepng() was useful.  Thanks for that.  Do you have any suggestions on how I could reference the posted data in catcher.php?

Comment: I apologize, I missed your comment about php://input, I will give that a shot now.

Comment: No problem. I'd added it to the answer after the initial posting anyways.

Comment: I was able to successfully resolve this issue with the help of both you and Brenden's help.  Thank you both so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your data isn't encoded as [multipart/form-data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Form_Data), it's just a PNG.

You have two options:

1. Encode the data correctly for a POST -- then you can read it from `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`.
2. Keep `post.php` how it is and read the raw data from [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) in `catcher.php`.

For option 1, it looks like [HttpRequest](https://www.php.net/HttpRequest) handles form encoding for you.

Comment: Perhaps there is some confusion here.  The process that I am posting in is in 3 files, with 2 separate posts.  The first file is compare.html which posts multipart/form-data to post.php which in turn uses the posted image and forwards it to catcher.php in the form of image/png post.

Comment: @EthanKeiley - What I mean is that `post.php` is not correctly forwarding the image, since it's sending raw data, but PHP's `$_POST` variable only contains form encoded data. Your current `post.php` will work if you change `catcher.php` to read directly from `php://input`.

Comment: Thanks Brenden, with help from you and Marc I was able to resolve this.  I really appreciate it!